# import React from 'react'; why vs code is showing cssSyntax error in the line for import

Tags: reactjs, npm-package

the import keyword is getting underlined and showing cssSyntax error and is getting wavey unerlined.I installed all the packages using npx create-react-app and now this error persists pls help me on how to fix this error?

Comment: For VSCode to show a a CSS syntax error, it sounds like you have the wrong file extension (Or a misconfigured VSCode) Without more details I'm not sure this is answerable.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with compiler. try to close compiler and reopen again/update vs code and make sure you have installed required extension for react ,JavaScript and typescript to... Happy coding.